# How do I know an arc direction?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

Although I have full information about the arc, I still don't know how to draw it. Precisely, I don't understand the explanation of the directions that I have.

Here is the information that I have:

Start point X=-40.0   Y=0.0   Z=0.0

End point   X=40.0   Y=0.0   Z=0.0

Center   X=0.0   Y=0.0   Z=0.0

Radius = 40.0

Direction   X=-0.0  Y=-0.0   Z=-1.0

Direction   X=-1.0   Y=0.0  Z=0.0

I put two possibilities. Please, can anyone tell which of them is the right one? and why? based on the information that I've mentioned.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiWM6.jpg)

Comment: What do the two(!) directions at the end mean?

Comment: I have no idea what do the directions mean, for this reason I don't know which arc is the right one.

Comment: What does $-0.0$ mean? Is that different from $0.0$?

Comment: Your figure is missing the minus sign on the starting $x$ coordinate.  As you did not put signs on the axes, it is not clear which one corresponds to $-z$.  That is the correct one for the first direction.

Comment: @Aretino, I don't know if there is any difference between -0.0 and 0.0

Comment: @RossMillikan, yes you are right, I missed the minus sign, also I've put both of the start point and the end point in wrong places in the figure, I will update the figure now.

Answer (score 1):

The direction should be a tangent vector to specify what plane the arc is in.  I take the first direction to say the half circle is in the $xz$ plane and below the $x$ axis.  The second says the circle is in the $xy$ plane on the $+y$ side of the $x$ axis.

Comment: @Aretino:  I missed the minus sign.  It was quite small in the font I got.  I have updated the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, I've made a mistake with the radius, it should be 40 not 20. I edited it.

Comment: OK, now we have two directions, each of which is sufficient to specify an arc.

Comment: The original drawing was created in Solidworks, after that it was saved as a STEP file which is a text file to describe the design . So, all the information that I mentioned (start point, end point, center, radius, direction 1 and 2) was gained from the STEP file. The confusing issue is that the arc was created in XY plane, however the directions do not make any sense. For that I asked the question.Although it sounds a terrible question, believe me it is not.